# Which R statistics tests to use in order to compare the effects of different variables on a test score

Tags: r, regression, anova, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

cross posted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742778/which-r-statistics-tests-to-use-in-order-to-compare-the-effects-of-different-var)

I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

I've got a data set which includes 'testscore', 'User Type (a or b)', 'Gender' and 'Age Group'. The data set has an N over 2,000 so considering the Central Limit Theorem, I'm not worried about normality (should I be?).
I've pasted a sample csv in Pastebin here http://pastebin.com/9AXT22Gu

Box plots (by User Type, Age Group and Gender) show me the difference between User Types, Age, Gender v testscore results. These differences might not exist in the sample csv though.

```
bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Usertype, y=testscore, group=Usertype)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Usertype))
bp
bp + facet_grid(Gender ~ AgeGroup)
```

My question is therefore: What are the most appropriate methods (available in R) to evaluate the effect and significance of 'Usertype' (and other variables) on the TestScore? Specifically, I'd like to:

1. Compare Usertypes over all and based on Gender and AgeGroup. i.e.
   Males in the agegroup 18-24 with a Usertype A score (significantly)
   higher than Males in the agegroup 18-24 Usertype B.
2. Establish whether Usertype effects testscore and control for gender
   and age. i.e. are the results mainly due to Age/Gender?

Currently, I'm homing in on Anova with a post-hoc TukeyHSD, but I'm no longer sure that's the right approach for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm also interested in the best way to visually represent output, but that's another story

Help and pointers in the right direction (to examples, books etc) would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer.  I created dummy variables for Gender and UserType and coded AgeGroup as 1 - 6. (should I have created 6 dummy variables for AgeGroup? ).  I then used Hierarchical Regression as described in this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgA8qY63dX0.
I put AgeGroup and Gender in the first block and UserType in the second block.  After running the model, I could see that UserType had an effect.  If you used the sample csv, your results may vary (I used a larger csv).

WRT to visually representing the data, I created a graph with testscore on the Y axis and age group on the Y axis.  I think plotted the mean test score for Males/Females for each user group.   I'm still looking in to better ways to visualize if, but I think I nailed the 'controlling for variables' question.

Please let me know if I missed a trick.

Thanks
Dave